# How to clear bunle value getting from some other activity...?

Tags: android, android-activity, bundle

// this is my main activity

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        System.out.println("onResume()");

        // getting the value form some other class(checking one the activity is started)
        try {
            bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            myFlag = bundle.getBoolean("KEY");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(".......Error.......");
        }
}
```

I am making the myFlag=true, my problem is when ever i change the orientation(ie restarting the activity), I want myFlag = false, but its remains true... Means I want to clear the bundle value once orientation change.
I have tried with bundle.clear() and bundle.remove("KEY") in onDestroy() method, but not working.

I already use this..

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        System.out.println("onDestroy()");
        if(bundle!=null) {
            bundle.clear();
                        // i also use the below statement
                       // bundle.remove("KEY");
        }
}
```

Comment: Read this document: [Handling Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html), you will get clue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this, you can have an idea

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            if (savedInstanceState.getBoolean("activity_restarting")) {
                // activity is restarting... Don't check mFlag..for that do something something here :)
            }
        }

    }



    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putBoolean("activity_restarting", true);

    }
```

I hope you can handle now

Comment: Hi Faizan, thaks for your help, its working now, thak you very much